# Не срабатывают триггеры у ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm, wpf-шаблоны

Пытаюсь отключить выделение `ListBoxItem`'ов. Переопределил стиль двух триггеров, но при наведении и выделении `ListBoxItem`'a они все равно срабатывают.

`XAML`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Winners}">
                <ListBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="8">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Content="Угадавшие участники игры:" 
                                                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                   VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                   BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 1"
                                                   BorderBrush="Black"
                                                   Padding="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ScrollViewer>
                                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ListBox.Template>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 0, 1"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 0, 1"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 0, 1"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StdWin}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу. Из того, что знаю я 1) нельзя переопределить триггеры заданные как ControlTemplate.Triggers (а у ListBoxItem они именно такие) 2) Нельзя и цвета вида Item.SelectedActive.Background перепределить, потому что они а) лежат в ресурсах контрола б) подключаются как StaticResource. Мне пришлось делать свой шаблон для ListBoxItem

Comment: Да просто если нужно совсем отключить выделение, и не нужен скроллбар, то следует использовать `ItemsControl` вместо `ListBox`.

Comment: @aepot пример бы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно совсем отключить выделение, то лучше использовать `ItemsControl` вместо `ListBox`.

```xml
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Winners}">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="8">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Background="LightGray" CornerRadius="8,8,0,0" Padding="3">
                        <TextBlock Text="Угадавшие участники игры:" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Padding="3">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StdWin}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То что нужно!) Весьма признателен!)